# compiler looking for an extra attribute within my function parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

Some context, I have a similar little more complex function which is under a class, and receives the same error. I do think this is just a concept problem that I have with functions.

Code:

```
def add(self, atr):
print(self.atr)

add("me")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "problem_file_2.py", line 5, in <module>
    add("me")

TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'atr'
```

Comment: Could you try to make an example that demonstrates the behaviour? As it is we can not see if you have any indentation problems, and that simple call to `add` seems suspicious since it looks like a function call, not like a method call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a function under class like one given below, `self` acts as the context of the instance of the class.

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        
    def add(self, atr):
        self.value += atr
```

In order to create an instance, you must call the constructor.

```
n = Number(5)
n.add(5)
print(n.value)
```

This will output

```
10
```

You are getting the error because you never created the instance.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class A:
  def add(self, atr):
    self.atr = atr
    print(self.atr)

A.add("me") # error
A().add("me") # works
```

A class is a type.
More objects can be of same type.

`a=A()` makes an object/instance of type A.

`self` is such an object of type A.

`a.add(atr)` is like `A.add(a,atr)`.